# RoR: using paperclip for video upload and transcoder with elastic transcoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this issue.

I need help to find a way to make paperclip work with elastic transcoder.

I need to be able to save an uploaded video in S3 Amazon bucket using paperclip and then transcode the uploaded video into 3 different format and save them back in the same bucket.

The issue is can I get all done together?

Comment: Well I am going to try to edit this with proper english so correct me if I change the original intention of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by using a gem called 'elastic_transcoder'

Here is a sample of what I have done using `elastic_transcoder`

- First get the url of the video you want to transcode excluding the `AWS domain name` and `bucket name`.

  `url = self.paperclip_video.url.split('/').pop`
  `url = url.drop(3).join('/')`

  you got the idea the above code varies depending on the url you get you just need the path as I said before excluding the `AWS domain name` and `bucket name`.
- Then get the path to the original video
  `input_url = url + '/' + self.paperclip_video_file_name`
- Then get the `filename` excluding the extension to user to generate the `output url` for the `transcoded video`

  `file_name = File.basename(self.paperclip_video_file_name, File.extname(self.paperclip_video_file_name))`
- Then create the output path

  `output_url = url + '/mp4_' + file_name + '.mp4'`

  For simplicity I am transcoding to one type which is `mp4`
- Create a new `elastic transcoding pipline`

  `pipeline = ElasticTranscoder::Pipeline.new`

  please note that you need to set first the pipeline on you `AWS` account moreover you need to set your `preset` for `mp4` conversion on your `AWS account`.
- Initialize your `pipline object` by passing your `pipeline_id` which you obtained from `AWS`

  `pipeline_front.pipeline '***************'`
- create a new `Jobs` object to pass you transcoding jobs to

  `jobs = ElasticTranscoder::Jobs.new`
- create new `Job`

  `jobs.create_job input_url, output_url, "**your pipeline_id**", "your preset_id", "#{url}/web_thumbnail-{count}"`

This will do the job and you can get the video transcoded.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use the elastic_transcoder gem with paperclip? Code snippet of the processor maybe?

Comment: @MoMolog sorry for late reply I have updated the answer. Hope my answer now is better and will help you or anyone.